# Getting super and sub classes of Dbpedia Ontology

Tags: entity, sparql, ontology, dbpedia

I am trying to get the **hierarchy** of super and subclass of **dbpedia ontolgy**.

**Sparql query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?superclass ?subclass 
 WHERE 
   {
     ?subclass                a  owl:Class    .
     ?subclass  rdfs:subClassOf  ?superclass
   } 
ORDER BY  ?superclass ?subclass
```

It gives me **all classes**. But when I am trying to get the counts of **entity inside classes**. Some **classes** have **entity** while **some** **don't have**.

*Sparql query to get the count of entity inside classes.*

**Getting** Entities:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label AS ?label 
                 ?name AS ?name 
                 ?link AS ?link
  WHERE
    {
                 ?link  rdf:type    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q12136>  .
      OPTIONAL { ?link  foaf:name   ?name                                    }
      OPTIONAL { ?link  rdfs:label  ?label                                   }
          FILTER( lang(?label) = "en" )
    }
```

**Not getting** Entities:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label AS ?label
                 ?name AS ?name 
                 ?link AS ?link
 WHERE
   {
                ?link  rdf:type    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18553493> .
     OPTIONAL { ?link  foaf:name   ?name                                      }
     OPTIONAL { ?link  rdfs:label  ?label                                     }
          FILTER(lang(?label) = "en" )
   }
```

Why some classes don't have entities? Or Am I doing something wrong? Any help please?

Comment: You edited the question based on the response/answer below... but do you consider the (non-programming) question to be answered?  If so, please accept the answer.  If not, please try to clarify your remaining question...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are talking about **classes** and not **ontologies**. I don't know why you think that entities are instances of ontologies, especially when you're talking about individuals/instances/resources.

Second, why shouldn't there be classes that do not have instances yet?

Comment: Sorry. Actually, I was thinking wrong. Thanks for showing the right way. I am talking about classes. Edited the question.